# SVN 1.6 move to another server

Tags: svn

I am really new to SVN and need some inputs in migrating SVN server. At my work  admin whoever set up SVN on server X left the company and currently we want to move the SVN repo from legacy server X to the new server Z and eventually want to decommission the applications. Since, we don't have any new enhancement we want to keep the existing SVN setup as it is to the new server. I have gone through old archives and  have come with steps like taking dump and then export to the new server. Instead can I just rsync/copy the entirefiles from the old server to the new server? Will it work? Is there a way to avoid taking this 50GB data and then build app in the new server. Can someone please advice? Can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, the configs may need some tweaking.
However this is a bad plan. svn 1.6 is very old.

You're on the path - export the repos from your old server... import them on the new with the latest version of svn. test it out. I should work... If not, fix it up and the swap the DNS entries when you're satisfied.